# Python: Misunderstanding about how imports work

Tags: python, google-app-engine, import

Here is my loader class, **ItemLoader.py**:

```
from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.tools import bulkloader
import models

class ItemLoader(bulkloader.Loader):
    def __init__(self):
        bulkloader.Loader.__init__(self, 'Item', [('CSIN', int), # not too DRY...
                                                  ('name', str),
                                                  ('price', int),
                                                  ('quantity', int)
                                                  ]
                                   )

loaders = [ItemLoader]
```

Here is my kind implementation, **models.py**:

```
from google.appengine.ext import db

class Item(db.Model):
    CSIN = db.IntegerProperty()
    name = db.StringProperty()
    price = db.IntegerProperty() # OK that it's an int?
    quantity = db.IntegerProperty()
```

These are essentially copied from GAE [instructions](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html#Creating_Loader_Classes). When I run `appcfg.py`, I get this error:

```
ImportError: No module named models
```

What am I doing wrong? If I take out that import statement, I get a different error:

```
... No implementation for kind 'Item'
```

**UPDATE 1:** I tried copy/pasting directly from Google's instructions, and I get that same import error.

**UPDATE 2:** Changed the name of the kind implementation to `models.py`. Still doesn't work. Both `ItemLoader.py` and `models.py` are in the same directory.

**UPDATE 3:** hacky solution: put them both in the same file! It works, but what am I not understanding about imports?

Comment: Where does that ItemLoader class live -- in a `.py` file in the same directory as `models.py`?  From the error it would seem it doesn't.

Comment: @Alex The two files are in the same directory (see above).

Comment: and is that directory your current directory as you run appcfg?  Otherwise you'll have to alter the python path, as the answer below suggests.

Answer (score 1):

You must add models directory to the PYTHONPATH. From docs:

```
(which is in your PYTHONPATH, such as the directory where you'll run the tool)
```

If you don't do that, python can't find your module.